# Python - Constructing a column of a pandas data frame on conditions and queries

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

I have to build a column of a dataframe based on some conditions. I usually use the np.where() function but in my case, as expected, it does not work. I need to add a column to the df2 based on the values ​​of another column, in our case 'Let'. When it is equal to 'a' it is necessary to search for a value in another data frame, in particular it must return the 'Dates' field of df1 where the 'Species' field is equal to the value of the 'Animal' field in that index ('Let' == a). The same reasoning for 'Age' and 'Mesure'. My code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Species' : ['Falcon', 
                     'Falcon','Falcon','tiger','Falcon','Dog'],
               'Dates': ['30-01-2019', '30-01-2019','30-01-2018', '30-01- 
                        2017', '30-01-2019', '30-01-2021'],
                   'Age'   : [ 2.55, 23, 31, 2, -12.55, 31]})



df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Animal' : ['Dog', 
              'Falcon','Dog','tiger','Falcon','cat'],
              'Mesure' : [2.55, 23, 31, 2,22,4],
               'Let' : ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a','b']})     

np.where(df2['Let'] != 'a', 1, df1[(df1['Species'] == df2['Animal'])& 
    (df1['Age'] == df2['Mesure'])]['Dates'])
```

The output is dthe column:

```
 30-01-2019 (first record of df1)
 30-01-2021 (last record)
 30-01-2018 (third record)
 30-01-2017 (fourth record)
```

Comment: can you include the output of your current code as well as your expected/desired output?

Comment: i have modified the code for a better example.

Comment: not exactly. now that I look, I'm wrong with the example. now I correct. then I explain

Comment: now there are the correct data frames

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps.

```
new = df2.merge(df1, how = 'left', left_on = ['Animal','Mesure'], right_on = ['Species','Age'])
new = new.drop(['Species','Age'], axis = 1)
new.loc[new['Let'] == 'b','Dates'] = np.nan
new
```